# How to save leaft map in shiny app that contain marker and some other filters

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard, r-leaflet

I Want to download the Map view that contains all my filters and markers  and I want to upload it to the server so users can log in and download what they need

I tried the solution to this question This
but it always gives me an error:- **Warning: Error in : webshot.js returned failure value: 1**

Here is my sample code that similar to my code

```
header <- dashboardHeader( title = "simple", uiOutput("logoutbtn"))

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")) 
body <- dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(), uiOutput("body"))
ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "black")


credentials = data.frame(
  username_id = c("EEE"),
  passod   = sapply(c("123"),password_store),
  permission  = c("basic"), 
  stringsAsFactors = F
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  login = FALSE
  USER <- reactiveValues(login = login)
  
  observe({ 
    if (USER$login == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$login)) {
        if (input$login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          if(length(which(credentials$username_id==Username))==1) { 
            pasmatch  <- credentials["passod"][which(credentials$username_id==Username),]
            pasverify <- password_verify(pasmatch, Password)
            if(pasverify) {
              USER$login <- TRUE
            } else {
              shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
              shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
            }
          } else {
            shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
            shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  
  
  output$logoutbtn <- renderUI({
    req(USER$login)
    tags$li(a(icon("fa fa-sign-out"), "Logout", 
              href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)"),
            class = "dropdown", 
            style = "background-color: #eee !important; border: 0;
                    font-weight: bold; margin:5px; padding: 10px;")
  })
  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    
    if (USER$login == TRUE ){ 
      sidebarMenu(
        
        menuItem("something",selectInput("region", label = "Choose Region:",
                                       choices = c("All", "ee", "ww"), multiple = F)),

        #Button
        downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
        
      )
    }
  })

 foundational.map <- reactive({
   leaflet( width = 1000, height=500) %>% 
      addTiles("spm")%>%
                           addPolygons( 
                             weight = 0.5, opacity = 1, color = grey)


 output$body <- renderUI({
    
    if (USER$login == TRUE ) {
      
      if(input$userName == "All") {
        if(input$region == "ee"){
          if(input$project != "All") {
            location_input <- location_ee %>% filter(Project == input$project)
            foundational.map() %>%
              addCircleMarkers(data=  location_input, 
                         lat =  location_input$Latitude_y,
                         lng =  location_input$Longitude_x,
                         radius = 2, col = location_input$color) %>%
              addLegend(position = "bottomright",  colors = c("blue", "orange", "green"),
                        labels =c("Hsos 791", "jmmi 29", "camps 6"), opacity = 1,
                        title = "Number of Covarge Area")
      } else {  
        foundational.map() %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data=  location_ee, 
                           lat =  location_ee$Latitude_y,
                           lng =  location_ee$Longitude_x,
                           radius = 2, col = location_ee$color) %>%
          addLegend(position = "bottomright",  colors = c("blue", "orange", "green"),
                    labels =c("Hsos 791", "jmmi 29", "camps 6"), opacity = 1,
                    title = "Number of Covarge Area")}}
}else {
          loginpage
        }
    
  })

 user.created.map <- reactive({
    
    # call the foundational Leaflet map
    foundational.map() %>%
      
      # store the view based on UI
      setView( lng = input$map_center$lng
               ,  lat = input$map_center$lat
               , zoom = input$map_zoom
      )})
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename = paste0( Sys.Date()
                     , "Covarge_map"
                     , ".pdf"
  )
  
  , content = function(file) {
    mapshot( x = user.created.map()
             , file = file
             , cliprect = "viewport" # the clipping rectangle matches the height & width from the viewing port
             , selfcontained = FALSE # when this was not specified, the function for produced a PDF of two pages: one of the leaflet map, the other a blank page.
    )
  } # end of content() function
) # end of downloadHandler() function

}
```

**Where Location_ee can be any data.frame that has some gis information like Latitude,
Longitude**

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a kind of basic shiny app - but one that does what you describe, meaning that it allows its user to create a leaflet map based on input provided, and saves it to his file system as a self contained HTML document - a few years back. As the use case is a simple one it should be still valid.

You are welcome to the source code on GitHub - https://github.com/jlacko/leaflet-generator - and the runnable app itself is on https://www.jla-data.net/eng/jla-leaflet-generator/

In the source code of the app pay a special attention to the download handler function - https://github.com/jlacko/leaflet-generator/blob/master/listek-eng/server.R#L129